# Get "change" to work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, internet-explorer-9, onchange

I cant get .change() to work with an input in Internet Explorer 9. It works in all other browsers (that I've tried) but not IE 9.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.myInput').change(function () {
        alert("hi");
    });
});
</script>

<input class="myInput" />

</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your definition of "it works"?

Comment: You are using version of jQuery 1.4.4.. try to get latest, 1.6.3 for example

Comment: You are also missing `DOCTYPE` declaration, you better add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. Just as you said it DOES work. The problem was that I also had a validate script on the input with a regualar expression that didn’t work in IE9 (but in IE8).
Big thank you though…

Answer (score 1):

Just tell IE that it's textbox by adding proper attribute:

```
<input class="myInput" type="text" />
```

Edit: while still better practice to specify the type, that wasn't the problem, it [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/TBCvU/) in IE9 for me, so like Jon asked: what you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

It works when I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/WUEXD/

I would recommend you to have a doctype on the page, which would be the XHTML doctype as you are using XHTML in your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

To avoid problems with picky browsers, put the input in a form, and set the `type` attribute:

```
<form>

<input type="text" class="myInput" />

</form>
```

Comment: There's no point using XHTML unless you don't care about IE and your server is configured to send XHTML with the correct MIME type, which is usually not the case.

Comment: @Tim Down: That may be, but the code is XHTML so it should have a matching doctype.

Comment: Agreed that it needs a doctype, but the code is not necessarily XHTML. `<input class="myInput" />` is valid HTML5.

Answer (score -2):

Use keypress instead of change.

```
$('.myInput').keypress(function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: The OP clearly wants to trigger the function when the input has changed